# Homework, how to use resolution to prove these inferences are valid?

Tags: logic

I am kind of a layman in this area, and now I have to prove these:

1. $P\rightarrow Q,\neg Q\vdash\neg P$
2. $P\rightarrow Q\vdash\neg Q\rightarrow\neg P$
3. $P\rightarrow Q, Q\rightarrow R\vdash P\rightarrow R$

I have to use resolution to prove these inferences are valid, but I do not know how to do it. Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do 1., try to do the other ones yourself

> First write the given clauses as disjunction of literals, we have $P\to Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q$ and $\neg Q$. To prove $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ using resolution, we moreover assume $\neg \alpha$ and check if we can resolve the empty clause. Here $\alpha =\neg P$, so $\neg \alpha \equiv P$. So we have the set of clauses 
>   $$ \{ \neg P \lor Q, \neg Q, P\} $$
>   For each pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ if there is a literal $l$ such that $l$ is contained in $\alpha$ and $\neg l$ in $\beta$, resolve $\alpha$ and $\beta$: We can resolve $Q$ from $\neg P \lor Q$ and $P$, so we have 
>   $$ \{ \neg P \lor Q, Q, \neg Q, P\} $$
>   now from $Q$ and $\neg Q$ we can resolve $\bot$, hence are done.